# Design graph when intermediate nodes are involved in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I am very new to graph database . Kindly help me for the solution.

Suppose I have three nodes 'Customer','Debit card' and 'Transaction'.
I have a sentence "Customer uses debit card for transaction".

Design Approach 1:[My Design 1 - Make seperate node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVrpY.png)

Design Approach 2:[My Design 2 - Add inside property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YnLS.png)

if I want to answer this question "what does customer use for transaction ?"

Both approaches can provide the correct answer 'Debit card'.

MY DOUBTS :
If I follow the second approach (add debit card inside property), I cannot determine that which all nodes uses the 'Debit card'

I am confused about which method is standard one.

Answer (score 0):

You should follow your instincts here.

In general, important entities in your graph tend to be best represented as nodes, especially if they need to be associated with several nodes at once.

Another thing to keep in mind is (aside from legacy indexes), relationship properties can't be indexed or looked up quickly, so if you had a requirement for queries that start from a debit card number, only approach 1 would allow you to look up the card based on the number quickly (you'd want an index or unique constraint on the label+property).